# Legal throwins at lineouts

Tags: rules, rugby-union

Is it legal for a team to score a try from a line-out quick thrown-in after

- the same ball went into touch,
- the referee has blown for the lineout,
- the linejudge has his flag up and his arm out, and
- the defending team is still on their way to the line-out?

In this situation, the attacking team has an advantage as they outnumber the opposing team considerably, similar to when there are more players on one side of a formed line-out.

In my opinion, the referee should ensure that the line-out be formed properly as it already has been called. Furthermore, I believe a penalty kick should be awarded to the other team. This is due to the team taking the throw in being off-side as it cannot be judged a straight throw in.

Answer (score 3):

[Law 19](http://laws.worldrugby.org/?law=19) covers when a quick throw can be taken as opposed to a lineout.

The touch judge or assistant referee should not put his arm up until a quick throw cannot be allowed because of a different ball or the line out is formed.

In the description you give above its play on.

Also bear in mind that as soon as the line out is formed, the throw in can take place regardless of whether both sides are ready.